# repeatedly using same dataframe view in join in pyspark sql

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the code below in pyspark.  In the code I'm creating 3 sub query views.  I then join the 3 views together to form a final pyspark-sql view.  What I'm finding is that if I run the pyspark-sql as is using the daily_sku_t view that I create earlier in the code, it throws a really long error that I've supplied the top line of below.  If instead I first write the daily_sku_t view out to parquet and then read it back in, the code runs without error.  The problem is it makes the overall code take longer to write out and read back in.  Is there a way to solve this issue without having to perform the action writing out?  I tried creating another copy of the view with a different name but that threw an error too.

example:

```
daily_sku_t.write.mode("overwrite")\
.parquet('s3://stuff/copy_daily_sku_t/')

copy_daily_sku_t=sqlContext.read.parquet('s3://stuff/copy_daily_sku_t/')

copy_daily_sku_t.createOrReplaceTempView("daily_sku_t")
```

code:

```
# product_repeat

product_repeat_product_cycle_days_query="""select
            dateclosed, s.product_id, s.tz_brandname,
             datediff(dateclosed,
            lag(dateclosed, 1) over (partition by s.tz_brandname, customer_uuid, s.product_id
        ORDER BY
            dateclosed ASC, ticketid )) as product_cycle_days
        from
            (select distinct dateclosed, product_id, tz_brandname, customer_uuid, ticketid 
            from daily_sku_t
            where (customer_uuid is not null) and (trim(customer_uuid) !='')
            and (product_id is not null) and (trim(product_id) !='')
            -- and (tz_brandname is not null) and (trim(tz_brandname) !='')
            and (dateclosed is not null) and (trim(dateclosed) !='')
            ) s 
    
        """

product_repeat_product_cycle_days=spark.sql(product_repeat_product_cycle_days_query)

product_repeat_product_cycle_days.createOrReplaceTempView("product_repeat_product_cycle_days")

product_cycle_days_sub_query="""select
        dateclosed, storeid, tz_brandname, producttype, productsubtype, size, product_id, 
        floor(avg(product_cycle_days)) as product_cycle_days
    from
        (
        select
            t.dateclosed, t.product_id, t.storeid, t.producttype, t.productsubtype, t.size, t.tz_brandname,
            a.product_cycle_days
        from daily_sku_t t
        left join product_repeat_product_cycle_days a
        on trim(a.product_id)=trim(t.product_id)
        and trim(a.dateclosed)=trim(t.dateclosed)
        and trim(a.tz_brandname)=trim(t.tz_brandname)
        where (t.customer_uuid is not null) and (trim(t.customer_uuid) !='')
            and (t.product_id is not null) and (trim(t.product_id) !='')
            and (t.dateclosed is not null) and (trim(t.dateclosed) !='')
        
        )
    group by
        dateclosed, tz_brandname, producttype, productsubtype, size, storeid, product_id"""

product_cycle_days_sub=spark.sql(product_cycle_days_sub_query)

product_cycle_days_sub.createOrReplaceTempView("product_cycle_days_sub")


product_repeat_gross_query="""select
        dateclosed, storeid, tz_brandname, producttype, productsubtype, size, product_id,
        sum(product_repeat_gross) + (rand() / 10000) as product_repeat_gross
    from
        (
        select
            t.dateclosed, t.product_id, t.storeid, t.producttype, t.productsubtype, t.size, t.tz_brandname,
            case
                when ticketid = first_value(ticketid) over (partition by t.product_id, t.customer_uuid
            ORDER BY
                t.dateclosed ASC,ticketid rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) then 0
                else grossreceipts
            end as product_repeat_gross
        from daily_sku_t t
        where (t.customer_uuid is not null) and (trim(t.customer_uuid) !='')
            and (t.product_id is not null) and (trim(t.product_id) !='')
            and (t.dateclosed is not null) and (trim(t.dateclosed) !='')
        
        )
    group by
        dateclosed, tz_brandname, producttype, productsubtype, size, storeid, product_id"""

product_repeat_gross=spark.sql(product_repeat_gross_query)

product_repeat_gross.createOrReplaceTempView("product_repeat_gross")



product_repeat_query="""select a.dateclosed, 
a.storeid, 
a.tz_brandname, 
a.producttype, 
a.productsubtype, 
a.size, 
a.product_id,
b.product_cycle_days,
c.product_repeat_gross
from (select distinct dateclosed, tz_brandname, producttype, productsubtype, size, storeid, product_id from daily_sku_t) a
left join product_repeat_gross c
on trim(a.dateclosed)=trim(c.dateclosed)
and trim(a.storeid)=trim(c.storeid) 
and trim(a.tz_brandname)=trim(c.tz_brandname) 
and trim(a.producttype)=trim(c.producttype) 
and trim(a.productsubtype)=trim(c.productsubtype) 
and trim(a.size)=trim(c.size) 
and trim(a.product_id)=trim(c.product_id)
left join product_cycle_days_sub b
on trim(a.dateclosed)=trim(b.dateclosed) 
and trim(a.storeid)=trim(b.storeid) 
and trim(a.tz_brandname)=trim(b.tz_brandname) 
and trim(a.producttype)=trim(b.producttype) 
and trim(a.productsubtype)=trim(b.productsubtype) 
and trim(a.size)=trim(b.size) 
and trim(a.product_id)=trim(b.product_id)


"""

product_repeat=spark.sql(product_repeat_query)

product_repeat.createOrReplaceTempView("product_repeat")
```

top of error:

```
An error was encountered:
'Resolved attribute(s) _w5#7888 missing from discounts#7149,_w5# ....
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")` before you perform the `JOIN` operation

Answer (score 0):

In a single query you can achieve it by making use of the 'with' clause.
It will look something like below.

```
spark.sql("""
with tableA as select ..., --tableA subquery goes here
tableB as select ..., --tableB subquery goes here
tableC as select --tableC subquery goes here
//refer the temp tables created above in the following query
select * from tableD join tableA join tableB....""")
```